# How to build puppeteer form source

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I need to build the puppeteer from source, I have checkout the source below Github repo. 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Can anyone guide me to build it from source.

Comment: what do you mean by "build from source"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to use latest puppeteer version, you can use this - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#q-how-do-i-trytest-a-prerelease-version-of-puppeteer , and if you want to contribute, use this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-setup

Comment: I tried to build puppeteer so that I can change/customize any behaviour inside the puppeteer source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puppeteer source has a `build` command on it's `package.json` [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/17bc6515deec8229afb73edc3869f497e6c06e10/package.json#L20).

Easiest way would be to `git clone`, change codes, build it with `yarn run build` then use `yarn link`.

Then where you want to try it, you can use `yarn link puppeteer` wherever you want to use your local version.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know the result.